# MV3 Background Service worker vs Event page

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Currently in MV3, Chrome supports Service worker while Firefox & Safari opted for Event pages.

SW in MV3 is discarded and then restarted and all variables are reinitialised.

- What happens to variables in event pages?
- Do they have to be recreated every time the event fires (within event callback)?
- What are the practical differences between SW & EP in extension development?

Comment: It's the same as event page. The main difference is the lack of DOM and other foreground-only API. The entire script executes in both cases, not just the event listener, so your variables will be new each time, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73208288), see also [how listeners work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516519) in SW and event pages.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. Since EP has more functionality than SW, a background SW written for Chrome extension should work on Firefox without any hassle, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you don't use SW specific events (onfetch, oninstall, onmessage).